# System Verilog code for upcounter with synchronous reset that counts till 15 and again sets to zero

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Is this logic correct with respect to system Verilog guidelines?

```
always_ff (posedge CLK)

 begin 

  If (!rst)

    count <= 4'b0000;

Else

Count<= count+1'b1;

End

assign count=4'b1111 ? 4'b0000 :count;
```

Comment: The code you have above is just full of errors. Why don't you have a look at the www and search for an example of a synchronous counter in Verilog.

Comment: Did you even try to compile it?

Comment: the only thing which is related to system verilog in this code is `always_ff`. The rest is generic stuff. And as it was mentioned in previous comment,  it consists of  syntactic and logical errors, nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do this. You get the wrap behavior for free.

```
logic [3:0] count;

always_ff (posedge clk) begin 
  if (!rst)
    count <= 4'b0000;
  else
    count <= count+1'b1;
end
```